# How to construct non-square isometry matrix or non-square unitary matrix in matlab (Or mathematically)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, isometry, unitary-matrices

Based on my understanding for the unitary and isometry matrices is that unitary matrix is a square matrix whose columns (equivalently, rows) form an orthonormal basis, means that $U*U’ = U’*U = I$ where I is the unity matrix , * is multiplication operation and ' is the transpose operation.  On the other hand, isometry matrix only has  columns which form an orthonormal basis and it’s not necessary to be square, that means that only  $U*U’ = I$

My question is how can I construct random isometry matrix ? either in matlab or theoretically in mathematics. Or in other words, is it possible to construct non-square unitary matrix ?

Comment: Can you create a random matrix of a given size and use Gram Schmidt to make the columns orthonormal? Or does this not fulfill your request?

Comment: Are you considering "portrait" matrices with $r>c$ (more rows $r$ than columns $c$) ? In this case, the word **basis** shouldn't be present in  "has columns which form an orthonormal **basis**" because a basis of $\mathbb R^r$ should possess $r$ vectors, i.e., $r$ columns, contradicting the $r>c$ assumption.

Comment: @Laray I think Gram Schmidt can be used for constructing squared unitary matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to construct a random isometry "portrait" matrix in Matlab with $r \ge c$.

Take a random array $r \times c$ and apply it the "orth" operator which is a kind of Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization:

> ```
> r=5;c=3;% resp; number of rows and columns
> M=rand(r,c);
> N=orth(M)
> N'*N;%gives I_3
> N*N';% doesn't give I_5
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But, what's about if I want the $N*N'$ to be be $I_5$ ? I fact, what I need is to have the $N*N' = I_5$. I doesn't matter if it's real matrix or complex.

Comment: As $N\in \mathbb{R}^{5\times 3}$ is can maximally have rank $3$. So $N\cdot N^T$ can maximally have rank $3$ and not rank $5$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer